# firefox window thumbnails not showing from Favorites icon

Tags: firefox, context-menu, favorites

I have launched firefox and have several windows open. At one time, I could right-click on the firefox icon in the Favorites bar and I can click on "All Windows" and I would see thumbnail images of all the windows, in a single row, and I could click on one to bring that window forward.

Now, when I right-click on the firefox icon and click on "All Windows", I see, at the very top of the screen, a few pixels of a picture. It is as if the pictures are being displayed above the actual window and I can only see 5 pixels of the bottom thumbnail.

How can this be fixed? Other than re-installing my system? I am running 20.0.4 and firefox is "Mozilla Firefox 103.0".

I would also like to extend the behavior of the context menu that one sees from the firefox icon in the Favorites bar. If anyone has coding suggestions, please speak up. Much thanx.

Comment: Well, I upgraded from 20.04.03 to 20.04.1 and the problem went away. I did not get an answer, though. Something became corrupted and having to wait until a new operating system install occurs is not a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

See what happens in full-screen mode `f11` If you're using a version downloaded off of Mozilla.org, try the version that comes with your version of Ubuntu. If `F11` works to see the thumbs, try moving the scroll bar to make the thumbs visible. Otherwise, after you click all windows, wait for a few seconds. Firefox sometimes hides parts of the screen until it's still for a few seconds, or scrolled to the top.

If you think a problem is caused by corruption, you can always reinstall with `$ sudo apt install firefox --reinstall` But if you're not willing to press one key--`F11`--to try to fix the problem, I think the level of effort put forth is inadequate.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is not it. I think the data structure that held the data for the screens became corrupted and I could not see how to verify this. Obviously, the upgrade changed the shape of that data and the data was regenerated, which fixed the problem. So, how to examine the data? Also how to fix the data directly or cause a regeneration?